# How to clear apache shiro session?

Tags: grails, shiro

I used apache shiro session for the authentication and authorization.

Am able to login with different user and permission and roles but actual problem is whenever i call a signOut function looks like shiro session is not getting wiped off.

The evident for this is whenever i clicked logout it comes main screen and if i use browser back button i can go back for the last screen.

My signOut function looks like this

```
// Log the user out of the application.
SecurityUtils.subject?.logout()
webRequest.getCurrentRequest().session = null
session.invalidate()    

// For now, redirect back to the home page.
redirect(uri: "/")
```

Any help on this really appreciated struggling for this from past 2 days

Comment: What version of the Grails shiro plugin are you using?

Comment: am using the shiro 1.2.0

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with version version 1.1.4 of the shiro plugin.

```
def logOut() {
    SecurityUtils.subject?.logout()

    redirect(uri: "/")
}
```

Comment: Am also using the same code it does logout but shiro's session is still active.If i use back button of a browser i can go back to the previous page.  If i leave itfor say approx 1hr shior's session is getting timed out and everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

This is due to browser cache. You can configure to reset your browser cache in ShiroSecurityFilters file.

```
 class ShiroSecurityFilters {
 def filters = {
    requestHeadersFilter(controller: '*', action: '*') {
             after = {
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
            response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0)
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
            response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store")
        }
    }
```